# IE and css via use of jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I would like to set a css properties like this

```js
$(#something).css({'color':'red'});
```

for example, but instead I write

```js
$(#something).css({'color':'#cafe'});
```

and nothing is done on IE. what is wrong with that ? The former works whilst the latter fails..

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to use keywords instead of color, so that you can use it multiple places. For that you should have to store it in a variable and then when you applying CSS through jQuery use variable instead of color.

Example:

```
var cafe = '#482610';
$('#something').css('color', cafe);
```

Answer (score 0):

## cafe isn't a valid hex color..

try #FFFFFF for example or #CCCCCC

Answer (score 0):

There's no such color string as `#cafe`. That's all. Maybe `cafe` without the hash symbol, I've never tried. :-)

If you mean it to be a hex value, Ramon has it right, though you can also use short versions (3 characters):

`#caf` would work.

Comment: Yes, I should have added two more 00 at the end of of cafe :-)

Comment: #cafe00 is quite a nice chartreuse. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You still have to use valid color values (with `#cafe` not being one - `red` is ok though as it is a predefined color) like you would do in a stylesheet.

See **[this list](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_colornames.asp)** of prefined colors you can use for that. If you don't want a predefined color use hex-format either with 3 or 6 digits like `#ff0000` or `#f00` or RGB-notation `rgb(255,0,0)` (the examples being red in all cases). See **[the specs on that](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-color/#rgb-color)**

Btw. usually you would have to wrap your jQuery-selector in `'`s like :

```
$('#something').css({'color':'red'});
```

Comment: Well spotted with the selector.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-color/#rgb-color

The spec says:

> The format of an RGB value in hexadecimal notation is a ‘#’
> immediately followed by either three or six hexadecimal characters.
> The three-digit RGB notation (#rgb) is converted into six-digit form
> (#rrggbb) by replicating digits, not by adding zeros. For example,
>
> ## fb0 expands to #ffbb00. This ensures that white (#ffffff) can be specified with the short notation (#fff) and removes any dependencies
>
> on the color depth of the display.

So you can't depend on invalid values such as `#cafe`, some browsers might try to be forgiving by padding extra 0's but you really can't depend on it. So stick with the spec :)